# math overflow for a not very overflowing calculation in python

Tags: python, math, numpy, overflow, exponent

The calculation for which I'm getting the math overflow number is:

```
e2 = math.exp([[-20.7313399283991]])
```

There are actually more extreme numbers that I've done than this, why is this causing an overflow?

I get this error:

```
OverflowError: math range error
```

Answer (score 2):

`math.exp()` operates on scalars, not on matrices.

You can use it like so, without the square brackets:

```
>>> math.exp(-20.7313399283991)
9.919584164742123e-10
```

If you need to operate on a matrix, you could use [`numpy.exp()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html):

```
>>> numpy.exp([[-20.7313399283991]])
array([[  9.91958416e-10]])
```

This computes the element-by-element `e**x` and returns an array of the same shape as the input. (Note that this is not the same as the [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential); for that, there is [`scipy.linalg.expm()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html).)

Comment: Thanks, but when I do `numpy.exp([[-20.7313399283991]])`, I get another error... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467970/attributeerror-exp-while-using-numpy-exp-on-an-apparently-ordinary-array

Answer (score 1):

You should call it without the `[[]]`:

```
e2 = math.exp(-20.7313399283991)
```