# AttributeError: exp when using numpy on data loaded using scipy.io.loadmat

Tags: python, numpy

I get the following output from the unit test below:

```
[[array([[-1.57079633]])]]
[[array([[0.+1.57079633j]])]]
<module 'numpy' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_TestWECTrain_BasicEnv_SetupAndStepping (__main__.Test_exp)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_exp.py", line 34, in test_TestWECTrain_BasicEnv_SetupAndStepping
    expsigmatphase = np.exp(tmp)
AttributeError: exp

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Here is the unit test

```
import unittest
import os
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

class Test_exp (unittest.TestCase):

    def test_exp (self):

        data_file = "test_buoysimoptions.mat"

        buoysimoptions = sio.loadmat (data_file)

        t = 0.0
        phase = buoysimoptions['SeaParameters']['phase']
        sigma = buoysimoptions['SeaParameters']['sigma']

        sigmatminusphase = sigma * t - phase; print (sigmatminusphase)
        tmp = -1.0j * sigmatminusphase; print (tmp)
        print (np)
        tmp = np.asarray(tmp)
        expsigmatphase = np.exp(tmp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The input file (2.9kB) can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/psq1gq8xpjivrim/test_buoysimoptions.mat?dl=0

Why do I get the error `AttributeError: exp`?

Note this is identical to ["AttributeError: exp" while using numpy.exp() on an apparently ordinary array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467970/attributeerror-exp-while-using-numpy-exp-on-an-apparently-ordinary-array) but this question was never answered and provides no minimal example like I do.

This is in Python 2.7, In Python 3.5 I get:

```
[[array([[-1.57079633]])]]
[[array([[0.+1.57079633j]])]]
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_exp (__main__.Test_exp)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_exp.py", line 25, in test_exp
    expsigmatphase = np.exp(tmp)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exp'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Edit: some further information on the loaded data

I expected `buoysimoptions['SeaParameters']['phase']` to just be a numpy array, but it seems not, see below, which ultimately causes the error

```
>>> phase = buoysimoptions['SeaParameters']['phase']
>>> phase
array([[array([[1.57079633]])]], dtype=object)
>>> phase = buoysimoptions['SeaParameters']['phase'][0]
>>> phase
array([array([[1.57079633]])], dtype=object)
>>> phase = buoysimoptions['SeaParameters']['phase'][0][0]
>>> phase
array([[1.57079633]])
```

do I need to index [0][0] always to just get the actual array? What is the right thing to do here? If I use the last one, the exp error goes away.

Comment: What's the output of `print(type(tmp), dir(tmp))`? The issue seems not to be about `np` but `tmp`.

Comment: Uhm. On the command line I can reproduce it. But I see that `tmp.dtype` is `O`... if I try to create an array as `a = np.array([[0.+1.57079633j]], dtype=object)` then `np.exp(tmp)` fails with  `AttributeError`, but if I specify `dtype=complex` then I get the correct result... maybe you only need to specify the `dtype` somewhere? Re why on the command line works but not from the script: you probably use a different python and hence different library versions. Maybe in some cases it ends up with `dtype=O` vs `dtype=complex` and you get that error

Comment: I think the problem is that the fields of the loaded structure are like the following: `array([[array([[1.57079633]])]], dtype=object)`

Comment: @NilsWerner, nope, definitely not, did you see the output of the print (np) statement?

Comment: This seems more a problem with your file... if somebody sent you a file that was created in a weird way you'll obtain a weird result. Can you change how the file is created? Maybe it's there that you have to fix something.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta,file was created with `save ('test_buoysimoptions.mat', '-v7', '-struct', 'buoysimoptions')` in Matlab, the standard way to do so.

Comment: Checkout the [options to `loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html). I'm not an expert in scipy/numpy or matlab, but maybe you just need to specify `mat_dtype=True` or `squeeze_me=True` or `matlab_compatible=True`?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta, I'll give these a go

Comment: np.exp` applied to an object dtype array tries to apply an `exp` *method* to each element.   `loadmat` uses object dtype arrays (2d) to represent matlab structs and/or cells.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the answer is simple, these loaded variables were themselves oringinally matlab structures, and I was omitting the index when retrieving them, the correct thing to do is the following (note the extra [0,0]s when retrieving phase and sigma):

```
import unittest
import os
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

class Test_exp (unittest.TestCase):

    def test_exp (self):

        data_file = "test_buoysimoptions.mat"

        buoysimoptions = sio.loadmat (data_file)

        t = 0.0
        phase = buoysimoptions['SeaParameters'][0,0]['phase']
        sigma = buoysimoptions['SeaParameters'][0,0]['sigma']

        sigmatminusphase = sigma * t - phase; print (sigmatminusphase)
        tmp = -1.0j * sigmatminusphase; print (tmp)
        print (np)
        tmp = np.asarray(tmp)
        expsigmatphase = np.exp(tmp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```